# SQL ORACLE - "Table or view does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Item
(
    Tree_ID VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY
    REFERENCES Tree(ID),
    Order_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Order_ID) REFERENCES Order_Form(Order_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Tree
(
    ID VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    Roottype VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Roottype) REFERENCES Rootstock(Rootstocktype),
    Variety VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Variety) REFERENCES Variety(Name),
    Age NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (Age >= 0),
    Pot_Size NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (Pot_Size >= 0),
    Price NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (Price >= 0),
    Available_On VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Can someone explain to me why im getting this error code?
Thank You

Comment: Your are referencing `Rootstock` and `Variety` but have no table definitions for them.

Comment: In Order_item, you cannot create a FK to Tree until that table exists.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you sir

Comment: @SMor thank you sir

Comment: You have the answer to your immediate question, but let me make some other observations.  You have several column (pot_size, for instance) that are NUMBER and NOT NULL, but then you put a check constraint that they must be => 0.  Given NUMBER NOT NULL, the check constraint is redundant.  Also, you have a column AGE.  I don't know what it is the age of, but its always a mistake to store age of anything, because 'age', by definition, is always increasing.  Well, except age_at_death.  Instead, you should store the DATE from which AGE is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle checks if all objects you are creating exists. When you try to create table Order_Item, your schema is referencing another table that you are creating later. The solution is create first tables without references and finally most complex tables.